# Do we need the [gnss-gps] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I noticed that we seem to have two tags for the Global Positioning System: [gps] and [gnss-gps]. These two tags seem to have exactly the same meaning—namely, the Global Positioning System, which is a particular global navigation satellite system (GNSS).

I don't see any reason to keep the [gnss-gps] tag.

Comment: related discussion: [GPS vs GNSS tags, do we need both?](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1717/6031)

Answer (score 12):

I agree, furthermore I'd recommend renaming the [gps](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gps) tag to the generic [gnss](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnss), to cover the rest of the constellations.

By 2020 the total number of GNSS systems should be 4: GPS, GLONASS, BeiDou, and Galileo.

Comment: Yup, keep it simple

Comment: If we rename, then I'd _highly_ recommend making [tag:gps] a synonym of [tag:gnss], as I expect far more people will be trying to tag questions [tag:gps] than [tag:gnss]. I'm not sure, though... is it really ideal to have only one tag for all 4 systems rather than separate ones? Are they similar enough that this is a reasonable thing to do?

Comment: Old a/c receivers are GPS only, quad constellation receivers will be the norm. IMHO most people are not aware which constellation(s) they are using, and they don't know the term GNSS.  Synonym or not, some existing questions will end up with the wrong tag. In addition, when gps is synonym with gnss, there is no specific tag for the GPS system.

Comment: I think it doesn't really matter if gps is renamed to gnss, and a new gps is created, or gps stays as is, and a new gnss is created. Either way, it will be a bit messy. Either way, we should end up with [gnss] [gps] [galileo] [beidou] [glonass], because it seems logic. To me, at least. Time will tell if people are using all 5 tags.

Answer (score 4):

I want to express that [ymb1's answer](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3819/100) got my upvote, but that I have one reservation which I thought was worth putting here as an answer so it can be voted on and commented as appropriate.

I agree that the current tag [gnss-gps](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnss-gps) should be renamed to [gnss](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnss). However, I have a reservation about separate tags for the other systems - mainly that colloquially most people know the name "GPS" and will tag as such when what they really mean is the more generic "GNSS". I also do not think we will ever get enough questions about a *specific* system (such as "GLONASS") that would warrant having separate tags. And even if a question *is* about a specific system, tagging with [gnss](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnss) is still useful.

Therefore, my suggestion is as follows:

- rename [gnss-gps](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnss-gps) to [gnss](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnss)
- synonym [gps](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gps), [glonass](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glonass), [beidou](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beidou), [galileo](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/galileo) to [gnss](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnss)

Note that [earthscience.se seemed to agree with my point](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/gps-vs-gnss-tags-do-we-need-both) regarding the colloquial use of the term "GPS".

Comment: Fully agreed. Also note I did not propose separate tags. The *regional tag + gnss* was deemed too complicated and has since been removed.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that there's no reason to keep the [gnss-gps](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnss-gps) tag.

My thinking would be that questions about GNSS in general should be tagged [gnss](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnss) and questions about a specific system should be tagged with that system's name.

Alternatively, we could make the specific system tags be synonyms of [gnss](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gnss), but I really don't see the need to do that at present. I think it's fine to have both a generic tag and specific ones for each system.